# C++ destructor recycling

Tags: c++

I saw a strange piece of code of c++ online, I want to know what's deep logic happened in the destructor.

I query a lot of knowledge online about c++ destructor, but I still not found an answer.

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A;
struct B{
        set<A*> sets;
        ~B(){
                cout << " b destructor invoked" << endl;
        };
};
struct A{
        B* b;
        ~A(){
                cout<< " a destructor invoked" << endl;
                b->sets.erase(this);//here will produce error, but why?
        }
};
int main(){
        A a;
        B b;
        a.b = &b;
        b.sets.insert(&a);
        return 0;
}
```

the above snippet will produce below errors.

out:

```
b destructor invoked 
a destructor invoked 
*** Error in `./a.out': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000001291c20 
*** Aborted (core dumped)
```

this error message that said I am probably double free or corruption.But Why?

However when I rewrote the struct `B` like below then all error disappeared.

```
struct B{
        set<A*> sets;
        ~B(){
                cout << " b destructor invoked" << endl;
                sets.clear(); //use clear method on sets
        };
};
```

when I used the `clear()` method in `B` destructor, then all error disappeared.

out:

```
b destructor invoked 
a destructor invoked
```

I don't know what's the deep logic in it.

Question:

why the error message will disappear when I add `sets.clear()` in `B` struct?

thanks in advance!

Comment: `b->` The `b` object does not exist in `~A`, cause it destructs first.

Comment: if  `b` object does not exist in `~A`, why I add `sets.clear()` in `~B`   then all the error disappear?

Comment: I think `b` should be exist in `~A`

Comment: It does not. Dereferencing `b` pointer `b->` is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> b destructor invoked
> a destructor invoked
> ```

Clearly, b is destroyed first. This is because variables are destroyed in reverse order of declaration.

At that moment, `a.b` becomes invalid. It no longer points to a B object. The object that it used to point to no longer exists. Next, a is destroyed. In its destructor it attempts to access a member by indirecting through the invalid pointer. The behaviour of the program is undefined.

> why the error message will disappear when I add sets.clear() in B struct?

Because the behaviour of the program is undefined. There is no guarantee that it will crash.

Comment: Does "undefined behavior" depends on run environment?

Comment: @V.Wu It can depend on anything, including the run environment. It can even depend on the phase of the moon. Nothing about the behaviour of the program is guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

For local variables, destruction happens in the opposite order with respect to construction.

```
int main(){
        A a;
        B b;
        a.b = &b;
        b.sets.insert(&a);
        // b destructed here
        // a destructed here
        return 0;
}
```

So, when `~A()` runs, `a.b` is no longer a valid pointer.